Ads test beginning December 3, 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on December 3, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

Which ads? I have no adblock on and not seen a single ad yet...

Those of us with 200 rep have the reduce ads privilege. You can still opt in to see ads via your settings page where you'll find an “enable advertisements” setting if you have this privilege.
